# Behavior of a Java process in case of OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

What would be the behavior of a Java program on getting [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). Is there any defined behavior? Will the process crash or would it go into wait/sleep state?

*Update:* if I am not handling it in my code?

Comment: sleeping with an OOM error would have what advantages?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

And `OutOfMemoryError` is handled like any other exception:

- If it is caught, then nothing more happens.
- If it is not caught, then either the [threads](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#getUncaughtExceptionHandler%28%29) or the [threads groups](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29) uncaught exception handler handles it. This pretty much always leads to the thread being stopped.

*However* there are two factors that are not really there in other exceptions:

- `OutOfMemoryError` is an [`Error`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) and not an [`Exception`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html). This means that it's *very unlikely* to be caught anywhere: You should not try to catch an `Error` generally (with very few exceptions) and it's not usually done, so the chances of it being handled are rather low.
- When an `OutOfMemoryError` happens and no object become eligible for GC because of that, then you'll *still* have little memory left and chances are that you'll run into the exact same problem again later on.

And if the thread this happens to is the only non-daemon thread (often, but not necessarily, that's the main thread, that executes the `main` method), then that thread getting killed results in the whole JVM shutting down (which is often perceived as "a crash").

So the **tl;dr** is: It will *probably* kill the thread, and if the memory-issue is not solved, then this can happen to more and more threads.

Comment: +1 for "the only non-daemon thread", although I guess the main thread is likely to be doomed to an `OutOfMemoryError` shortly afterwards in any case.

Comment: @Raedwald: that can easily happen, but need not be the case: sometimes the unrolling of the stack makes enough object eligible for GC that the out of memory situation is solved by that alone. For example if a big import of data fails due to an OOM-Error, it can happen that the rest of the application continues unaffectedly (but you could have bad luck and get the OOM-Error in another part first).

Comment: Good point. For a multi-threaded server, you actually want that behaviour, so a big request dooms itself rather than killing the server.

Answer (score 1):

You can't determine the state of program when OutOfMemoryError occurs. If you are not catching Throwable then your program will terminate with the stacktrace. Even if you are catching Throwable, you should call System.exit since there is no point in recovering from it. "Error" is generally thrown by JVM, as oppose to Exception, which is application/programmer specific.

Answer (score 1):

OutOfMemoryError should be considered unrecoverable and the behavior of the JVM after such an error has been raised is undefined, so there is no point in expending effort to handle it. Any operations done after this exception is thrown by the JVM will have undefined behavior. They may execute, but more likely they will just cause another error to be thrown.