# Runtime exception not terminating the programm

Tags: java, linux, jar, try-catch, runtimeexception

As per my little-bit java knowledge Program supposed to be terminated after it throws runtime exception.

But in my application after throwing runtime exception it is not terminating ,and as i am executing it on linux i have to use *ctrl+c* to terminate it, Otherwise it just do not terminate.

I am creating jar on windows sytem and copy paste it in linux.

Also i have logging enabled in my application.

**Update:**
I am not catching any exception
No multithreading is used.

Comment: are you catching the exception?  it will only terminate if it bubbles all the way out of your code.

Comment: "after throwing runtime exception" How do you know it is throwing a runtime expcetion?

Comment: @Raedwald Its a custom exception and i can see the exception message

Comment: "i can see the exception message" and how can you see that? Exception messages do not magically appear. Either the JVM crashed and reported the message (_contra_ your claim), or your code has caught it and logged the message itself, in which case you already know that *you caught the exception*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does the program not terminate when a method that throws RuntimeException is called without handling the exception in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297654/why-does-the-program-not-terminate-when-a-method-that-throws-runtimeexception-is)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

A `RuntimeException` (or *any* `Exception` or `Throwable`) does *not* necessarily terminate your application.

It *only* terminates your applications if it's thrown on the *only* non-daemon thread *and* is not handled.

That means that *if either* another non-daemon thread is running *or* you catch the exception, the application will *not* be terminated.

[This recent answer from me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606953/behavior-of-a-java-process-in-case-of-outofmemoryerror/7607003#7607003) gives a summary of what happens (it's specifically about an `OutOfMemoryError`, but the idea is the same).