# Will OutOfMemoryError cause a thread to die?

Tags: java, multithreading, out-of-memory

Does an OutOfMemoryError cause a spawned thread to die?

As in will it exit from run()?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Behavior of a java process in case of OutOfMemoryError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606953/behavior-of-a-java-process-in-case-of-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, whether the Error was thrown within the thread or within another thread. Please observe the behaviour of the following Snippet:

```
public class Test implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            System.out.println("alive");
        }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Thread(new Test()).start();
        throw new OutOfMemoryError();
    }
}
```

You can easily see, the spawned thread is still alive, although the main thread will die instantly after the Error is thrown. There is, however, no guarantee at all, which thread will finally throw the error.

Comment: In what case will run() die off, before main() dies?

Comment: An exception or error will kill the thread, executing the statement which lead to the error or exception. That is, `run()` will die, if the memory allocation leading to the oome occured in the spawned thread and `main()` will die if the allocation happened there

Comment: @Jonathan: yes, but in the *specific* case of the OOM, it's *very hard* to *reliably* predict which thread "cause" the OOM. If Thread 1 allocated many, many megabytes of object right up until the possible value and *then* Thread 2 tries to allocate a few small objects, it's *entirely* possible that Thread 2 "gets" the OOM, even 'though (arguably) Thread 1 "caused" it.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not caught, any Throwable will cause the thread to terminate. Errors generally aren't (and shouldn't be) caught.

Answer (score 0):

An OutOfMemoryError sets the JavaVM in an undefined state. Running Threads do not get killed by rule, your Threads might still be running despite the one which had the Error (if you didn't catch it).

But Threads still might die because of low memory (e.g. not enough room for their stack frame) but this depends on the room left. The JVM simply gets unstable.

Answer (score 0):

Your Threads may be kept in Running state forever as they wait for memory allocation from JVM but since JVM is in unstable condition nothing is allocated and the status-quo is maintained for infinite time!