# Trying to understand the Java Out Of Memory Error and catching the throwable

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, out-of-memory

Recently I was asked to catch the Throwable in my code.
So we ran into an argument that we should do it or not, I gave an example of OutOfMemoryError that in this case even if we catch the error our code won't be processed further.

So to test this theory, we created sample code for it.

```
public class TestErrorInThread {

public static void test() {
    System.out.println("Running the test at time " + new Date());
    try {
        System.out.println("Inside try block");
        Integer[] array = new Integer[10000000 * 10000000];
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        System.out.println("Inside catch block");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    int arr[] = new int[100];
    System.out.println("Programme is still running...");

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
    Runnable runnable = TestErrorInThread::test;
    scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}}
```

To run the code we used the below command.

```
java -Xmx1m TestErrorInThread
```

We got the following output for it

Running the test at time Wed Jun 16 14:20:31 IST 2021
Inside try block
Inside catch block
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Programme is still running...

Running the test at time Wed Jun 16 14:20:36 IST 2021
Inside try block
Inside catch block
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Programme is still running...

Running the test at time Wed Jun 16 14:20:41 IST 2021
Inside try block
Inside catch block
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Programme is still running...

Running the test at time Wed Jun 16 14:20:46 IST 2021
Inside try block
Inside catch block
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Programme is still running...

Running the test at time Wed Jun 16 14:20:51 IST 2021
Inside try block
Inside catch block
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Programme is still running...

Why this program is able to run further, even it got out of memory error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Behavior of a Java process in case of OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606953/behavior-of-a-java-process-in-case-of-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: The output of the program is not matching the theory, why the JVM is not crashed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the meat of the code:

```
try {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[10000000 * 10000000];
} catch (Throwable e) {
    /* ... */
}
int arr[] = new int[100];
```

According to the output in your question, this is failing in the large allocation, recovering and succeeding with the small allocation.

> Why this program is able to run further, even it got out of memory error.

Short answer: because the JVM is designed so that it can recover from OOMEs in most circumstances.

In your example, the first `new` operator will result in a memory allocation request for a large amount of memory (see below).  The memory allocator will notice that the request is larger than what is available.  It will then (typically) trigger a full garbage collector to free up as much memory as possible, then repeat the request.

In this example, there is still not enough memory for the very large allocation.  The allocator then throws an `OutOfMemoryError` which is then propagated like any other exception.  At this point in time, there will be lots of free memory ... but just not enough for the huge allocation.

Then your code catches the OOME, and tries to allocate a much smaller array.  That succeeds, since the memory is available.

Your test application does this sequence repeatedly, and it behaves the same say each time.

> Why this program is able to run further, even it got out of memory error.

In your example, the JVM is only "out of memory" for the huge allocation request.  For a smaller request, there is no problem.

Note that the huge `new` did not *actually* allocate memory.  It tested to see if it *could* do the allocation, and decided it *couldn't*.

---

Basically, your "theory" is incorrect.  It is however *generally* a bad idea to attempt to catch and recover from OOMEs.  Here are some reasons:

1. OOMEs are liable to cause threads to terminate unexpectedly, leaving data structures in inconsistent states, notifications that won't be sent and so on.  Recovery can be problematic.
2. If recovery leads to the same request being repeated, you are liable to get the OOME repeated.
3. If the root cause of the OOME's is a memory leak, then recovering from an OOME is unlikely to fix the memory leak.  So recovery leads to the OOMEs increasing in frequency until the system grinds to a halt.

Of course, there are exceptions to all of the above.

---

There are a couple of other things to note.

1. Your allocation *appears* to be requesting an array with 10,000,000 x 10,000,000 elements.  However that is not actually what happens.   In fact, `10000000 * 10000000` is an `int` expression.  It overflows, and the result is truncated to `276447232`.  That is still very large, especially because you need to multiply by 8 to get the approximate array size in bytes.
2. Since your JVM's max heap size is only 1MB, it is likely that the allocator won't bother to run GC.  It would make no difference to the outcome.  However, if there was any chance that the GC could free enough memory, you can be assured that it *will* be run before the allocator gives up and throws an OOME.
3. The JVM's memory manager splits the heap into a number of spaces.  The details depend on the GC that you have selected.  When a really large object is requested, the allocator has to find a contiguous area of memory that fits in one space.  This can be impossible ... even though the aggregate free space should be large enough.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Stephen C, I am able to understand the OOME concept.  Can you refer me to a book where I can learn about these concepts?

Comment: I have no recommendations for you.

Comment: Okay, Just want to understand another thing, if I remove the try-catch block, it won't run further, it just gets hanged at initialization no error is printed on terminal.

Comment: Yes.  The tasks are throwing an OOME which is killing the executor thread.  Since you haven't set a `defaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`, uncaught exceptions on threads (apart from "main") will be silently ignored.  The executor service will create a replacement for the terminated executor thread.

Comment: Thanks,  for the reply Stephen.