# Making sure that Java returns exit code 137 on OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java

I have a use case where I want to make sure that a Java process exits with code 137 in case of OOM issues.

Here some experimentations I did:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<byte[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    while(true) {
        arr.add(new byte[4096]);
    }
}
```

MacOs result:

```
java oom.java
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at Main.main(oom.java:21)
echo $? 
1
```

So it seemed clear that the JVM answers with exit code 1 in the case of OOM.

So I tried:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<byte[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        while(true) {
            arr.add(new byte[4096]);
        }
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
        System.exit(137);
    }
}
```

Which gave the same result.
And this option: `-XX:+ExitOnOutOfMemoryError` which gave exit code 3.

Why `System.exit(137)` is being ignored? Anyway to achieve that?

Comment: You're still holding on to `arr` at the point where you're trying to handle the OOME, which means memory will be **extremely** limited, so there's a good chance that while trying to *execute* something as simple as `System.exit(137)` you run into yet another error (probably another OOME). Have you tried putting the `arr` declaration and filling it into its own method to ensure that `arr` goes out of scope before trying to handle the exception? You seem to be running into [the second problem mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7607003/40342).

Comment: Try putting this line inside the `try` block: `List<byte[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();` That way `arr` is out of scope when you enter the `catch` block - as indicated in the previous comment.

Comment: Good catch that was that! I was not expecting Java not to be able to run `System.exit`. Thank you.

Comment: @LoganWlv: the lesson to take away from this is: correctly handling any `Error`  can be unexpectedly complicated. It's best if you design your system with the assumption that the handling will fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik 137 status means that the JVM was killed by the outside process, and you can't enforce exiting with this status on OOM from within your app. I didn't find the official documentation, but this article confirms it http://journal.thobe.org/2013/02/jvms-and-kill-signals.html.

Basically, if you want to get the 137 code on OOM - your app should be killed by some other process on OOM. You can achieve that by using `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError` flag that executes some arbitrary script on OOM. I.e.:

##### /scripts/kill.sh

```
kill -9 $(ps aux | grep "OOM.java" | grep -v "grep" |  awk '{print $2}')
```

---

```
java -Xmx256m -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=/scripts/kill.sh OOM.java
echo $?
#
# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
# -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/scripts/kill.sh"
#   Executing "/scripts/kill.sh"...
[1]    4280 killed     java -Xmx256m  OOM.java
137
```